# How can I jump to files from vim opening them in a separate tab?

Tags: linux, vim, vimrc

I have installed `tags` so I can jump to a function body in another file via `CTRL + ]`
I know that I can do `gf` to jump to another file.
I know that I can do `CTRL-w s` to split the vim window.
What I don't know and I am very interested in, is how can I combine the first 2 with the last.
I.e. how could I jump to another file via tag or `gf` *opening* the file in a separate tab?

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908269/opening-ctags-in-new-tab-in-gvim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split and open a new file at the named tag with the command `:stag`, it appears
to default to the binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>.

You could bind that to whatever then:

```
map <F2> :stag
```

If needs to be done in a tab, then, you can do it in two steps:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>

Or you can map it:

```
map <F2> :tab split <CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
```

For the `gf` equivalent of opening in new tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>,`gf`

or window split:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>,`f`

And again if you want to split AND then open in new tab,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>,`f`    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: Yeap. This works for `ctags` +1. How about `gf`?